# dragmove events acting up with Firefox & React

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, reactjs, draggable

I need to track coordinates from dragmove events, but for some reason this does not work properly on Firefox. I.e. `evt.pageX` and `evt.pageY` are always zero.

```
render(){
   return (<div draggable={true} onDragMove={this.handleDragMove} onDragStart={this.handleDragStart} />
}
handleDragStart(evt){
   console.log(evt);//this works
   evt.dataTransfer.setDragImage(new Image(),-999999999999,-999999999999);
   evt.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'oh ffs firefox'); //dragmove events wont get triggered at all without this
}
handleDragMove(evt){
   console.log(evt);//these get triggered
   console.log(evt.pageX+" "+evt.pageY);//always zero
}
```

I'm using Firefox 47 on Ubuntu 16.04 (but obviously need it to work on ~all versions of Firefox);

Comment: What do you mean by `does not work properly` ? What are the errors,  the symptoms ? Please be more specific.

Comment: console.log(evt.pageX+" "+evt.pageY);//always zero

Answer (score 0):

In my case the component to be dragged is very large, so I managed to work around this by setting `onDragOver={this.handleDragMove}`, and ondragover events seem to provide coordinates.